# How can I output raw unescaped html from this Rails route/helpers?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, escaping, routes, helper

I am trying to use the following bit of code to generate a link on my page

```
%h2= link_to '{{ label }}', product_path('{{ id }}'.html_safe)
```

This is actually part of a larger HTML block which will serve as a javascript template, and I will later parse using `Underscore.js` to fill in the `{{ id }}` and `{{ label }}` placeholders.  So I would like rails to output something to my HTML like

/products/{{ id }}

However, it keeps escaping the spaces and brackeets, and giving me

```
<a href="/products/%7B%7B%20id%20%7D%7D">{{ label }}</a>
```

So the url_helper is escaping my string, even though I don't want it to.  How can I force it to not do this?

I've tried

```
%h2= link_to '{{ label }}', product_path('{{ id }}'.html_safe)
%h2= link_to '{{ label }}', product_path(raw '{{ id }}')
%h2= link_to '{{ label }}', raw(product_path('{{ id }}'))
```

and

```
%h2=raw( link_to '{{ label }}', product_path('{{ id }}'.html_safe))
```

But none of them work

EDIT:

Another way to play with this is from rails console,

```
include ActionController::UrlWriter

ruby-1.9.2-p0 :010 > product_path '{{ id }}'.html_safe
 => "/products/%7B%7B%20id%20%7D%7D"
```

Any help appreciated... thanks

Thanks

Comment: It's 2019 and we still face similar problems!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about `CGI::unescape(product_path('{{ id }}')` ? (with the `require 'cgi'` that goes with it.)

I believe this is Ruby 1.9.2 only but it seems to be the version you're using.

Comment: For the record your solution seems to be ageless since it still works with Ruby 2.6.3 and Rails v5.2.3! Thanks!

Comment: Adding a comment to this 10 years old answer of mine as it got a vote recently: If you do this, make sure the `unescape`d data isn't user-controlled as it could open the door for XSS.